# Wooslider custom css

Tags: plugins, css

I recently purchased Wooslider plugin and would like to add custom css to override the Woothemes slider defaults.

However if I add custom css to the theme css file it gets overridden by the wooslider css since that css comes after my theme css in the head of the document.

Is there a way around this? some method or Wordpress script that forces my theme css to appear after the wooslider css perhaps, that would be a more elegant solution than putting css style tags into the head of the document? I was curious as to how other people deal with this issue?

Comment: It looks like this issue is well documented, just use more specific styles on your css compared to those used on the plugin or alternatively put the <?php wp_head(); ?> function above the theme stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) and/or [enqueue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) your stylesheet and hook it to [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) with a priority high enough that it loads after the Woothemes default.

```
function load_my_style_wpse_87804() {
  wp_register_style( 'mystyle', get_template_directory_uri() .'/path/to/mystyle.css');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'mystyle' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_my_style_wpse_87804',100);
```

You may need an even higher priority (third parameter), but eventually you should get one high enough.

This is, of course, assuming that Woothemes and the slider enqueues properly.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I figured that could be a potential method but was never sure how to make my css trump that of the others. Its like the z-index in html and css.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna change the CSS, you need to use their tool "WooDojo" ( http://www.woothemes.com/woodojo/ ) and actívate the "WooDojo Custom Code" feature (:

It may help...