# Display Something in the Header After All Styles are Loaded

Tags: css, actions, wp-enqueue-style, wp-head

I'd like to include a functionality in a theme that will overwrite styles from previously included CSS files. For this purpose, I need to be able to display a `<style>` in the header after ALL stylesheets have been displayed.

Is there a hook to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook to `wp_enqueue_scripts` with a high priority number. For example:

```
function load_my_style_wpse_90225() {
  wp_register_style( 'mystyle', get_template_directory_uri() .'/path/to/stylesheet.css');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'mystyle' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_my_style_wpse_90225',1000);
```

That should reasonably load last in line.

Basically the same answer as here: [Wooslider custom css](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87804/wooslider-custom-css)

### Refernce

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Wasn't aware that the priority parameters exists for actions too.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is generally not recommended, we can hook to the `[wp_print_styles][1]` action, which displays after `wp_head`, `wp_enqueue_scripts`, and `wp_enqueue_styles`.

So (in functions.php):

```
function my_theme_custom_css_handler(){
    echo '<style>custom css here</style>';
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'my_theme_custom_css_handler');
```

For more information and a full listing of actions, you can check the [Action Reference in the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

Comment: Creating a new style sheet and calling it last in the queue would be the proper way to do this. Else you could just add the styles to the header  directly. I don't see the point of this either way.

Comment: Linking to styles directly in the header is not recommended by the WordPress Codex and is a common reason for rejecting a theme from approval in the Theme Repository.

Comment: Yes but you were already going to use a method that was not recommended. What is the difference? Beside when I said directly I meant with style tags `<style></style>`